# Bash variable substitution on find's output through exec

Tags: bash, find, exec, substitution, built-in

Is there any way to apply [Bash variable substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) on `find`'s output? I know I've seen someone do it on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to find that particular post anymore.

**As an example**, let's say I want to rename files ending in `*.png` to `*_copy.png`. I know I can do this using `rename` but it's just a thought experiment.

Now I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
find . -name "*png" -exec mv "{}" "${{}%.*}_copy.png" \;
```

Which results in an *invalid substitution*. Of course, I could first assign the output to a variable and then apply substitution in a sub-shell, but **is this really the only way?**

```
find . -name "*.png" -exec bash -c 'var="{}";  mv "{}" "${var%.*}_copy.png"' \;
```

Or **is there any way this can be achieved directly from `{}`?**

**Consensus**

As *Etan Reisner* remarked, a better and safer way to handle the output of `find` would be to pass it as a positional argument:

```
find . -name "*.png" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.*}_copy.png"' "{}" \;
```

Comment: Editing an answer (or even a consensus summary) into the question is frowned on, as it makes that answer immune from the normal review, voting, and other community-based management. Consider adding a answer flagged "community wiki" if you want to have an answer that builds on others' work without being presented under your name / for your own rep gain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to get the question. Basically you are asking if something like:

```
echo "${test.png%.png}"
```

could be used to get the word `test`.

The answer is no. The [string manipulation operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) starting with `${` are a subset of the [parameter substitution operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF). They work only on variables, not with string literals, meaning you need to store the string in a variable before. Like this:

```
img="test.png"
echo "${img%.png}"
```

---

Just for travellers from Google, I would use `rename` for this particular task. (As the OP already mentioned in his question). The command could look like this:

```
find -name '*png' -execdir rename 's/\.png/_copy.png/' {} +
```

Comment: Yes I know, hence I said " I know I can do this using rename but it's just a thought experiment.". The question is about the substitution not about the renaming. Thanks for the reply though. -- P.S. you may want to quote the `{}` in your answer to handle spaces.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that. Let me add an example using bash.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I overlook stuff all the time on stack overflow, haha.

Comment: @ShellFish You don't need to quote `{}` since it will not being subject of word splitting

Comment: Oh, seriously? Wow I've quoted waaaay too many `{}` in my life then. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: (Note, that you indeed need to quote when you use `-exec bash -c ...` ) However, let me finsish the example first...

Comment: I have no issue, it works using `bash -c`. The question is whether the substitution can be achieved **directly** on `{}`, without having to store in a variable first and executing it in a sub shell. -- Perhaps through some escape sequence magic or something. But saving to a variable first seems like a redundant step, I'd like to do it shorter.

Comment: No. The part after the `{` and before the `%` is supposed to be a variable name. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF

Comment: If you include the fact that this can in no way be done in a single step, in your answer, I will accept.

Comment: Did it. Should be ok now. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, although I was hoping the answer was yes, haha. Anyway, thanks, +1

Comment: As a side point you should **never** embed `{}` directly into a shell script being run with `sh -c` or similar. It isn't safe for spaces/etc. (and no quoting doesn't fix that it just moves the issue to quote escaping). You should always pass it as a positional argument to the script instead.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks a lot for sharing that, I will definitely take that into account for the future!